# Transferring data from MySQL to Neo4j

Tags: python, mysql, django, neo4j, py2neo

We're in the process of migrating our MySQL based Django application to Neo4j. In MySQL, we have a Providers table and a Referrals table. The referrals table simply has a provider_from_id, provider_to_id, and a count column. It represents the referrals from one provider to another.

All of our 4+ million providers are already transferred into Neo4j. We are planning to represent the referrals as relationships in Neo4j between the different provider nodes.

Here's the issue, there are over 40,000,000 rows of referrals, and Neo4j seems to have incredibly terrible performance creating the relationships. Here is the script we're using to create the relationships. At the speed it is running, it will take over 2 months. Is there a better way to transfer this data?

```
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

# Link to providers index
providers_index = graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "Providers")

# Let's start transferring!
while True:
    total_so_far = num_transferred + num_orphaned
    referrals = Referral.objects.all().order_by('id')[total_so_far:total_so_far+1000000]
        if not referrals:
            break

        for referral in referrals:
            # We need to get the nodes for both providers (assuming they exist)
            provider_from = providers_index.get("npi", referral.provider_from_id)
            provider_to = providers_index.get("npi", referral.provider_to_id)

            if provider_from and provider_to:
                # We have matches for both providers, let's create the relationship
                graph_db.create((provider_from[0], "REFERRED", provider_to[0], {"count": referral.num_referrals}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that py2neo is using Neo4j's RESTful interface to do all these inserts, which means that it's going to do them one at a time, depending on your neo4j version.

Is there any chance you can use the [Batch Importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) which will import from a CSV on your initial load? If not, are you okay with using Java to write your own native batch importer for this?

Comment: I did rework it to use Py2Neo's batch interface. This way, I'm sending 3500 requests at a time, and I'm not bothering to check whether both providers actually exist first. It still does take awhile though. I've looked for documentation on Neo4j and CSV and I can't really find anything. Is it possible to import from a CSV and create relationships?

Comment: And by that I mean, the Batch Importer is meant to create nodes and relationships for those nodes. Can I pass it just the relationships csv file? It also needs to look up the nodes by their index, which I can't seem to find in the documentation.

Comment: I have that linked in my answer, but yes, it's meant as a one-time load for initial imports, and it reads from a CsV file.